# Use the jQuery FlexSlider plugin with a text nav?

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm looking to use the great little jQuery plugin, FlexSlider (http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) for a site I'm building.

The plugin's demo shows this working with a paginated navigation (of dots) below the images. I'm looking to replace this with a text navigation to select each slide. Any idea to this is posslbe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, solution found within the plug-in's own documentation. This is proof that I must read more!!

For anyone who happens to have the same question, you need to use the `manualControls:` reference in the API. More details can be found in the documentation (http://flex.madebymufffin.com/)

Comment: Hello Sheixt, I'm trying to accomplish this same thing with Flexslider. Did this solve your problem? I tried it and it didn't work for me, so I was wondering. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the delay @Davidz, by using `manualControls:` I was able to get it working fine. The other answer on this post (by @gschervish) is a good example. Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you're having problems still, post a JSFiddle (or similar) and I'll try to help :)

Answer (score 5):

Just to go into more detail what you need is `manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",` to enable text navigation and HTML something like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="flex-control-nav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail! :)