# Flex slider: numbered navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I have a flexslider in my website at: [this link.](http://partsgalaxy.info/)

I need to get a bullet point style or horizontal bullet point for navigation. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963138/use-the-jquery-flexslider-plugin-with-a-text-nav) I have added necessary `<ul>` and the code in JS, as like:

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: true,
    manualControls: $(".flex-control-nav li"),
  }); 
});
```

But i can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Alright seems that i'm just missing the necessary CSS. Just keep this here for future reference ...

Comment: it looks like you got it to work. just some styling issue..

Comment: yes fixed that too. How do I mark this question self answered?

Comment: I'm not sure.. normally there's an option answer your question or mark your question as answered. Maybe ask the moderators?